# tensorflow dataset splitting by participant

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to split a `tf.data.DataSet` on attributes, in my case participant or gesture. Currently, the dataset is a work in progress and the number of participants/gestures may grow. I originally set up a [tfds config](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/pull/3482) for this [gestures-dataset](https://tev.fbk.eu/technologies/smartwatch-gestures-dataset), but I haven't figured out how to configure participant/gesture splitting here either.

How should I split the `tf.data.DataSet` object? Currently, my data set exists as a single tf_record. I would prefer to keep it that way instead of generating different files for each participant and gesture and have to regenerate all the gesture tf-records when a new participant is added.

this works (method 1, gross):

```
subset = ds.filter(lambda x: (x['participant'] == 1 or x['participant'] == 2))
```

this doesn't (method 2, dream):

```
subset = ds.filter(lambda x: any(x['participant'] == p for p in [1,2]))
```

> OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.

I also attempted the same op as a decorated @tf.function.

example code with publicly available mnist dataset: [juptyer notebook on colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/10e8rWbbqvLL1thDU3wtxfLWwDNiPUzQR?usp=sharing)

**Is their a way to perform this operation in a similar style to method 2?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it by:

```
def predicate(label, labels_to_filter):
  return tf.math.reduce_any(tf.equal(label, labels_to_filter))


labels_to_filter = tf.constant([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype=tf.int64)
subset = dataset.filter(lambda x: predicate(x["participant"], labels_to_filter))
```

###### How it works:

`tf.equal` returns a boolean Tensor which contains `True` value if `label` matches one of the labels from `labels_to_filter`. `tf.math.reduce_any` returns `True` if there are `True` values in its input boolean Tensor.

Comment: You beat me to it.

equivalent:

`dataset.filter(lambda x: tf.reduce_any(x['label'] == [0,1,2,3,4]))`